# Python ImportError: from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertConfig

Tags: python, python-import, importerror, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I am trying to do named entity recognition in Python using BERT, and installed transformers v 3.0.2 from huggingface using `pip install transformers`
. Then when I try to run this code:

```
import torch
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset, DataLoader, RandomSampler, SequentialSampler
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertConfig

from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

torch.__version__
```

I get this error:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tokenizers/tokenizers.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: ____chkstk_darwin
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tokenizers/tokenizers.cpython-38-darwin.so (which was built for Mac OS X 10.15)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tokenizers/tokenizers.cpython-38-darwin.so
```

The error occurs in this line: `from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertConfig` but I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Please try a different version of tokenizers ([github issue](https://github.com/huggingface/tokenizers/issues/321)).

Answer (score 0):

Try `pip install tokenizers==0.7.0`